# Positiveness and symmetry of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If two real-valued matrices A and B satisfy following conditions that $AB = B^{T}A^{T}>0$ and $A = A^{T}>0$, could we say something about B?
for example 
$B = B^{T}>0$?

Answer (score 0):

Given $A = A^T$ is invertible, your condition $AB = B^T A^T$ can be written as $B^T = A B A^{-1}$.  If $B$ does not commute with $A$, then $B$ is certainly **not** symmetric.  For example, consider
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 2\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{b_{11} & b_{12}\cr b_{21} & b_{22}}$$
where this says 
$$ b_{12} = 2 b_{21}$$
If so, then 
$$ A B = \pmatrix{b_{11} & 2 b_{21}\cr 2 b_{21} & 2 b_{22}}$$
which is positive definite iff $b_{11} > 0$, $b_{22}>0$ and $b_{11} b_{22} > 2 b_{21}^2$.